# android: how to retrieve data from sql server using web service

Tags: android, sql-server, web-services

How to save and retrieve data from database. Can somebody give me a little help how to connect web service with database and in app, what would be the first step to start. Thanks.

Comment: check out this, should help http://mobiforge.com/design-development/consuming-json-services-android-apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Build a web server, which will be sending the JSon objects to you
2. Then use http calls to get this Json, like this:

> ```
>   public String httpGet(String url) throws IOException{
>             HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
>             DefaultHttpClient() _httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
>             BasicHttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
>             HttpResponse response=null;
>              response = httpClient .execute(get, httpContext);
>              StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
>              int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
>              return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
>         }
> ```

For more information, leave me a message, please.

Comment: Thanks dear. i'm so new to android and java. can give me some more piece of code to retrieve data from database and show the output in the listview.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Are u also the one who is working on the server side? if no, tell me more about the API they built

Comment: no i'm not working on the server side. i have web service made in asp.net and it has 2 methods of get and post. i want to perform the GET operation when user clicks the button from his phone. plz tell me how can i perform this thing.

Answer (score 0):

To communicate with a remote database: database on server for example you need to communicate with an API. They are several ways to build an API: PHP, ruby.
Communicating with a remote db is forbidden in most of hosts for security purpose.